# Is there a way to search for text at the beginning of a line in a common browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, javadoc

More specifically, is there a fast way to find a class in the All Classes javadoc?

Starting with this page:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html

Let's say I want to find the link for the class "Exception".  There are 447 matches on the page, but I want to go to the first one that starts with "Exception".  It's a slow process clicking next many times.  Years ago in the Mozilla browser I could open a find box and type a preceding space, " Exception" and it would go right to the Exception class.  Now, in Firefox and Chrome " Exception" matches nothing (which is arguably more correct, but less convenient).

Any suggestions?  Firefox solutions preferred, but I'll entertain solutions in other browsers that run on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/regex-find/?src=ss) to add regular expression to the search function.

Once done that search for `^Exception` to drop all the paragraph not starting with Exception